# socat reverse shell run python script

Tags: python, netcat, socat

I am new to using socat and was wondering if this was even possible. So my scenario is I am working on my OSCP and have a machine that I can get a reverse shell back on, let's say port 8888. I am trying to keep from writing to disk on this windows xp machine. Is there anyway I can set the socat connection so when the machine connects back to me it will be able run my python enumeration script, collect the output, and write the output back to my local disk?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your scenario details, but socat has the EXEC address type:

```
       EXEC:<command-line>
          Forks  a  sub process that establishes communication with its parent process and invokes the specified program with execvp() .  <command-line> is a simple command with argu-
          ments separated by single spaces. If the program name contains a '/', the part after the last '/' is taken as ARGV[0]. If the program name is a relative path,  the  execvp()
          semantics  for  finding  the program via $PATH apply. After successful program start, socat writes data to stdin of the process and reads from its stdout using a UNIX domain
          socket generated by socketpair() per default. (example)
          Option groups: FD,SOCKET,EXEC,FORK,TERMIOS
          Useful options: path, fdin, fdout, chroot, su, su-d, nofork, pty, stderr, ctty, setsid, pipes, login, sigint, sigquit
          See also: SYSTEM
```

so in your case if I understand it, you would want to do something like:

> socat TCP-LISTEN:8888 EXEC:/path/to/your/python/script

Comment: Thank you for the response. The first part I understand, socat TCP-LISTEN:8888, what I was wanting to do was to find a way for when the reverse shell opens on port 8888 I have someway to send my python script and have it execute. For example I have tried to open another listener so when the reverse shell comes in it is connected to port 9999 as well, but when i run my python script that is hardcoded 127.0.0.1 9999 it will not send to the remote machine, if that makes sense, almost like a way to forward my my traffic to and from the remote machine once it has connected to me.

Comment: I don't really know what your python script is doing, but on that reverse shell (I assume it is just a /bin/sh or similar spawn on the other end) TCP connection you can just write the shell commands and read responses. Uploading a whole python script and running it from memory is not that easy. socat will not do that.

Comment: Ahh ok maybe I should have mentioned this was a windows box also. The reason I was trying to use a script was because of automation and able to grab output for me etc.

Comment: So at the other end you have cmd, your script can "type" your commands via the TCP connection and read output. Otherwise there is little chance that there will be a python binary on a windows box.